# Different ways of iterating through pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am currently working on a short pandas project. The project assessment keeps marking this task as incorrect for me even though the resulting list appears to be the same as when the provided correct code is used. Is my code wrong and it just happens to give the same results for this particular DataFrame?

**My code:**

```
# Define an empty list
colors = []

# Iterate over rows of netflix_movies_col_subset
for t in netflix_movies_col_subset['genre']:
    if t == 'Children' :
        colors.append('red')
    elif t == 'Documentaries' :
        colors.append('blue')
    elif t == 'Stand-up' :
        colors.append('green')
    else:
        colors.append('black')
        
# Inspect the first 10 values in your list        
print(colors[:10])
```

**Provided code:**

```
# Define an empty list
colors = []

# Iterate over rows of netflix_movies_col_subset
for lab, row in netflix_movies_col_subset.iterrows():
    if row['genre'] == 'Children' :
        colors.append('red')
    elif row['genre'] == 'Documentaries' :
        colors.append('blue')
    elif row['genre'] == 'Stand-up' :
        colors.append('green')
    else:
        colors.append('black')
        
# Inspect the first 10 values in your list        
print(colors[0:10])
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? I haven't test it yet.

```
# Define an empty list
colors = []

# Iterate over rows of netflix_movies_col_subset
for t in netflix_movies_col_subset['genre']:
    if t == 'Children' :
        x='red' 
    elif t == 'Documentaries' :
        x= 'blue' 
    elif t == 'Stand-up' :
        x ='green' 
    else:
        x ='black' 
    colors.append(x)   
# Inspect the first 10 values in your list        
print(colors[:10])
```

Or you can do match case.

```
# Define an empty list
colors = []

# Iterate over rows of netflix_movies_col_subset
for t in netflix_movies_col_subset['genre']:
    match t:
    case 'Children':
        x ='red' 
    case 'Documentaries':
        x ='blue' 
    case 'Stand-up':
        x ='green' 
    else:
        x ='black' 
    colors.appent(x)    
# Inspect the first 10 values in your list        
print(colors[:10])
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll test it later when I’m home. From what you posted though it seems like my way works just fine and the task is being marked as incorrect because I didn’t loop through the DF using iterrows right ?

Answer (score 0):

I've always been told, that the best way to iterate over a dataframe row by row is NOT TO DO IT.

I your case, you could very nicely use df.ne()

First create a dataframe that holds all genres (df_genres)

then use

```
netflix_movies_col_subset['genre'].ne(df_genres, axis=0)
```

this should create a dataframe that has a line for every movie and columns for every genre. If a certain movie is a documentary, values in all columns would be False, only in the Documentary column it would be True.

This method is by multiple orders of magnitude faster than iterating with multiple if statements.

Comment: Thanks. And once you have the final data frame you’d just replace the strings with str.replace to get the correct colours and filter that into a list ?

Comment: or create another dataframe with color-values for each genre, then multiply those frames together (very fast) and sum each row (also very fast). This results in a new dataframe with one value per row that only has the color-value for each movie. this works because the only value left is the one that had the True in the other dataframe.